# CKEditor inline image upload not working

Tags: 8

I updated my 3 years old drupal site from Drupal 8.5.0 to 8.9.16 recently. Since the update, there are some issues which I am trying to solve.

In one of my article content type, I have a ckeditor to input article body. After the upgrade, I am facing some issue in adding inline images to the CKEditor. When I click on the inline image add button, it shows 'Loading...' and it goes for ever.
[image: Error screenshot]

When I checked the browser console, I saw the following error:

[image: Console error]

Can somebody plese help me?

Comment: I've had similar - not really reproduceable - problems previously. Try a full `drush cr` and reload the page without browser cache (hold shift while reloading, or open browser dev tools and disable cache in the network tab)

Comment: @Hudri, I tried the same what you suggested. Not helpful. Still same error.

Comment: What do you get in your watchdog logs (Reports > Recent log messages)?